# VPN & Separate Internet Connection Bonding

Tags: vpn, internet, adsl, bonding

I'm currently working with a large charity which has about 50 offices, each are interconnected with a dedicated VPN, which they use to access their secure database system, internal websites along with general internet usages.

One of their offices internet/vpn connection is extremely slow, pretty much dial-up speed, so we are looking into purchasing another ADSL connection and bonding them together.

Their database system, must go over the VPN and also intranet sites must be accessed over the VPN, but we want to send all over traffic over the new connection, what is the best way to set this type of network up?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Why bond two connections together? Why not just replace the current connection altogether with something that meets your needs?

Comment: Because we have to keep the VPN connection as it is, for them to connect to their HQ database and intranet

Answer (score 1):

use pfsense, both connection as routed. (e.g internal network 10.4.1.0, WAN1 NET 10.4.2.0, WAN2 NET 10.4.3.0 all /24)

set firewall rules on LAN to send traffic to the VPN Terminator (destination IP) via WAN2 IP (the IP of the ADSL Modem there)

set firewall to send all traffic via default - so the new ADSL Connection needs to be WAN1!